# Variance of integrated squared wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

So I'm trying to figure out the mean and variance of

$X = \int_{0}^{1} W^2(t) dt $

where $W$ is the Wiener process.

The mean I've worked out easily to be $\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$ but I'm having trouble with the variance. I am unable to find $E(X^2)$ in order to calculate $Var(X) = E(X^2) - (E(x))^2$ but something tells me this isn't the right way to approach this problem. Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Note: This is practice for an upcoming exam, not homework.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$E(X^2)=2\int_0^1\int_0^tE(W(t)^2W(s)^2)\mathrm ds\mathrm dt$$
Can you compute $E(W(t)^2W(s)^2)$ for $s\lt t$?

Comment: I get $E(W(t)^2 W(s)^2) = Cov(W(t)^2 W(s)^2) - \sigma^4 s t$. I'm not sure how to proceed from there. Sorry for my basic questions, I find myself struggling with these concepts.

Comment: You are merely rewriting things. Why the covariance would be easier to compute ? (It is not.) Sooner or later you will have to use the dependence structure of (W(t),W(s)). What is this dependence already?

Comment: Ok I finally got the answer in the book! After some working around, I got $E(W^2(s) W^2(t)) = E(W^4(s)) + (s)(t-s) E(W^2(t))$. However, I dont understand how you got the $2$ in front of the double integral? Could you explain that to me?

Comment: Typo in previous comment,  I meant $E(W^2(s) W^2(t)) = 3 \sigma^4 s^2 + (s)(t-s)\sigma^4)$

Comment: The factor 2 comes from the decomposition of the square $0\lt s,t\lt1$ into $0\lt s\lt t\lt1$ and its symmetric part.